# Payment against invoice

Tags: phrase-usage

> The item is sold **with** payment against invoice.

I mean ; the payment will be made after the invoice is issued. This is the payment method and they only sell their items in this way. If someone knows this method when I say this sentence would the phrase “ with payment against invoice” be natural?

Comment: What context?  I'm pretty sure that if you just made this active voice it would be better.

Comment: It sounds 'jargonese'. If you understand the jargon it might make perfect sense. As someone who never gets invoiced for things I buy, I wouldn't know what it meant. [Even if I do understand things like '30 day terms']. It's like starting an invoice with **"To:"**. It makes absolutely no sense, it's just convention.

Comment: It *might* be a "mealy-mouthed" way of saying *Because I do my business accounts properly, I always raise an invoice for every sale. So **don't** ask me to sell you something "under the counter / off the books" with the aim of us sharing the "evaded tax"*.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to say this would be something like

> We will pay after the invoice is issued.

(or, from the point of view of the seller)

> We will issue an invoice for each order.

What you write doesn't make much sense to me, and googling the phrase only finds your wordreference post. So it doesn't seem to be standard jargon.  I'd probably understand enough because you say "blah blah payment blah blah invoice"  so I know that you're saying something about paying and invoices, so I'd assume that "delivery with a 30 day invoice" is the expected method of billing (rather than cash up front)

Comment: I think *an invoice for each item* is ambiguous, but this doesn't matter anyway, in this context :).

Comment: perhaps "each order" is better.